# Is there a way to update data artifact in served MLFlow model

Tags: mlflow

I have an MLFlow model that is currently served locally.   There are several artifacts that are needed to run the model successfully and are initiated in the "artifacts" for the model.

Artifacts:

1. Path to the model weights file
2. Path to underlying data file that is used as reference for building features on the fly

This data file (2.) is updated weekly.

Is there a way to refresh said data within a served MLFlow model?

I can update the data weekly and "re-serve" the model but I was hoping there was a cleaner way to access the new data file within a model that is already served.